# hooking in Java?

Tags: java, profiling, hook

A hook is a process running to get data from other ([more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking)). I wanted to get the methods or functions using any application for access to a network, these methods are usually `WSAConnect()`, `WSASendTo()`, `bind()`, `connect()` and `sendto()` [these are the ones that need to get to the application].

I started testing, creating Runtime [Runtime.getRuntime (). exec (...)] with all possible methods [addShutdownHook (...);] and now I'm trying to ProcessBuilder [new ProcessBuilder (...);] and the famous BufferedReader [new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (proceso.getInputStream ()));] but I could not find the way to do it.

my principal request is how get (intercept) functions: WSAConnect (), WSASendTo (), bind (), connect () and sendto () that generates a program to communicate over a network. [using Java - Hooking]

Edit: ¿How can hooking at the library ws2_32.dll[ Windows OS  This contains the functions that I need ]

Comment: This sort of system-level stuff is *impossible* in pure Java, *extremely* difficult if you use something like JNI, and *very* difficult if you program in native Win32 (such as with C or C++). You may wish to investigate something like [Detours](https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/).

Comment: Another alternative to research would be [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/).

Comment: Your english is fine. Next time you dont have to excuse for that

Comment: Detours? first time I hear it. ¿What Java classes could start studying?

Comment: Jason ¿with AspectJ how capture and redirecting Functions and Methods ?

Answer (score 0):

That is counter to the design of java.

But Try to look at `AspectJ` which modifies the compiled class files to allow some kind of hooking.

Comment: Could you explain a little more?

Comment: With aspect j you can hook your own methods. I dont know if that works for foreign jar files. Please google for aspectJ. However the technique used in AspectJ could work on any jar

Comment: but if not is .jar, but rather .exe... AspectJ can make hooking?